# RxJs buffer until database insert (promise)

Tags: promise, rxjs, buffer, rxjs5

I have a data stream, with rapidly incoming data. I want to insert them into a database by keeping order. I have a database, which returns a promise, which is resolved when an insert is successful.

I would like to make an Rx stream, which buffers the new data, until the buffered data is inserted.

How can I do that?

Comment: And what's the problem? There's `buffer`, `bufferToggle` or `bufferWhen` operators.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea, how to use them. Trying to figure out, but don't know how yet.

Comment: Use `concatMap`, returning the promise from the project function. `concatMap` will do the buffering for you, but there is no back pressure in RxJS, so if your data arrives more quickly than you can write it, you will exhaust memory.

Comment: I can insert multiple records as well, that's why the buffer would be good, which collects the incoming data into an array until the previous promise is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to get exactly what you desire you would need to create your own operator.  Breaking from RxJS slightly you can get something like (warning, have not tested)...

```
export class BusyBuffer<T> {
  private itemQueue = new Subject<T>();
  private bufferTrigger = new Subject<{}>();
  private busy = false;

  constructor(consumerCallback: (items: T[]) => Promise<void>) {
    this.itemQueue.buffer(this.bufferTrigger).subscribe(items => {
      this.busy = true;
      consumerCallback(items).then(() => {
        this.busy = false;
        this.bufferTrigger.next(null);
      });
    });
  }

  submitItem(item: T) {
    this.itemQueue.next(item);
    if(!busy) {
      this.bufferTrigger.next(null);
    }
  }

}
```

Which can then be used as

```
let busyBuffer = new BusyBuffer<T>(items => {
  return database.insertRecords(items);
});
items.subscribe(item => busyBuffer.submitItem(item));
```

It isn't exactly purely reactive though and someone may be able to come up with something better.

Comment: Thanks! I created the same, but I hope someone can come up with a pure reactive solution :)

Comment: No sweat, good luck.  I was thinking of taking some kind of busy/free signal from the database and piping it back into the buffer method but you'd have to also add in the logic that the buffer should emit immediately if the database isn't doing anything.

Comment: Don't accept my answer if you want something better.  I don't mind.